# I want to use the moment.js (or any other script) in Postman Native App

Tags: javascript, testing, native, external, postman

I know the solution for Postman with Chrome Plugin....

the solution for my Postman with Chrome Plugin is
on my mbp
I've just add these line also put the moment.min.js (or any javascript file) as path described

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tester/moment.min.js"></script>
```

at the path

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/5.4.0_0/html/
```

in a file

```
tester_sandbox.html
```

for able to use moment in "Tests"
or

```
requester.html
```

for able to use moment in "Pre-request Script"

but i can't find where the Postman Native App keeps these file path....

i've already try another solution that i found on google about
add the script as an GlobalVariable then eval in "Tests" but it's still not work...

any ideas or any recommended ......

thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To use moment you need to add this to the top of you pre-request scripts or tests tab

```
var moment = require('moment')
```

Then you can use the module as per the docs.

```
moment().add(2, 'days').format()
```

Or whatever you need...

Comment: Oh..thanks, it's work.. how is that, could you explain me why and if i have my own somescript.js, how can i used it?

Comment: There are a few modules that the native Postman app comes with and moment is one of them. It also has Lodash and CheerioJS as well as some others. You can use the `eval(<my_script>)` for other things but I couldn’t give you a great answer about how to do that. "Postman-BDD" is an example of doing it this way.

Comment: You "could" store your custom JS script as a global variable and `eval()` it that way but it just seems like a poor workaround.

Comment: how can i check the list of supported modules for native Postman,  and sorry for my doubt, what's "Postman-BDD" for, i try to read but i still don't understand what it use for.

Comment: The list can be found on the [Postman Sandbox Docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) - The Postman-BDD module is just another way to construct tests using the `describe-it` syntax. I only mentioned it because it's the only real example i've seen of using an external script in Postman.