# How to set Postman Query Param to todays date?

Tags: api, postman

I am trying to get the data from a period of time. They are set to actual dates but I wanted to know if it was possible to always have it set to today's date without having to go back and change it every time.
[query params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Vp3.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following in the "Pre-request Script" heading below the URL field.

```
postman.setGlobalVariable('currentDate', (new Date()).toISOString());
```

Then add the variable wherever you are wanting to use the current date

```
{{currentDate}}
```

For example passing the current date as a query param

```
www.example.com/path?date={{currentDate}}
```

Comment: Nice - I would go for the newer `pm.globals.set()` syntax over the older `postman.setGlobalVariable`syntax though.

Comment: I had the same need and just discovered that you can easily add moment to postman : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936195/i-want-to-use-the-moment-js-or-any-other-script-in-postman-native-app/47937316